# How do I change GeckoFx proxy settings?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, geckofx

I'm using GeckoFx version 1.9.1.0, Mozilla XULRunner version 12.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Help With Proxy Username & Pass with GeckoFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958351/help-with-proxy-username-pass-with-geckofx)
See this answer for setting proxies programmatically. You can save and load the preferences to a file using the methods `GeckoPreferences.Save(string fileName)` and `GeckoPreferences.Load(string fileName)`

With XULRunner 12, you can't store preferences until you create any apps using XULRunner
(see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)

**To insert proxy settings manually in the xulrunner default profile:(XULRunner ~1.9)**

Goto d:\path\to\xulrunner\defaults\pref

Open the `xulrunner.js`, add the preferences you'd like to put.

Now, you can add preferences by following the below sample call at the end of the file:

```
pref("network.proxy.http", "web-proxy.domain.com");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

If you don't know what are the exact preferences or you want to know all the preferences, using your `GeckoWebBrowser`, navigate to `about:config`.

**For example:** `geckoWebWebBrowser.Navigate("about:config");`.

If the browser tells `"This'll Void Warranty"`, click `"I understand .."`.
Now, you can see all the preferences listed.

Comment: do you know of any way to set a proxy that requires credentials? I'm trying to set a proxy that requires credentials without getting the prompt to enter the username & password. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @mikro try setting the property: signon.autologin.proxy to true. This will prompt for the password one time and stores it in the login manager.

Comment: I got it figured out by using my own PromptService but thanks for the reply @IamStupid