# How to communicate with an HTTP/HTTPS proxy server (like Fiddler) from hooked socket calls?

Tags: sockets, https, proxy, hook, fiddler

On Windows 7, I would like to force a custom web browser application to talk to Fiddler proxy (for **both** HTTP and HTTPS) so I can play with the web traffic with Fiddler.

The custom browser application does not have proxy settings itself so I managed to write my own application to intercept ws2_32/wsock32 socket calls, namely *getaddrinfo()*, *connect()*, *send()* and *recv()*
using mhook library. Now, in the intercepted connect() call, if I instead connect to fiddler's IP and port, I am able to direct all HTTP traffic to Fiddler, as in the following code:

```
int WSAAPI Hookconnect(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen)
{
    int sock_type;
    socklen_t sock_type_length = sizeof(sock_type);
    getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, (char*)(&sock_type), &sock_type_length);

    if (sock_type == SOCK_STREAM) {
        WSAPROTOCOL_INFO proto_info;
        socklen_t proto_type_length = sizeof(proto_info);
        getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PROTOCOL_INFO, (char*)&proto_info, &proto_type_length);

        if (proto_info.iProtocol == IPPROTO_TCP)
        {
            // get port number from 'sin_port' member of sockaddr, and 'ntohs' function, wrapped in my own 'getPortFromSockaddr' call
            u_short port = getPortFromSockaddr(name);
            bool isHttp = (port==80);
            bool isHttps = (port==443);

            // for TCP, we connect to Fiddler instead
            sockaddr_in clientService;
            clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
            clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
            clientService.sin_port = htons(8888);

            // Trueconnect is the "true" socket connect API, if connecting to HTTP port
            if (isHttp)
                return Trueconnect(s, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof(clientService));
            else if (isHttps)
            {
                int retVal =  Trueconnect(s, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof(clientService));
                if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR) {  // connection is not necessarily failing for nonblocking socket
                    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                        return retVal;  // some sort of error
                    } else { // connection in progress for non-blocking socket
                        //check if socket is ready, with timeout = 15 seconds
                        int result = 0;
                        retVal = WaitForNonBlockingSocket(s, 15, result);
                        if (retVal == 0) {
                            // send CONNECT to proxy server for 'https tunneling', where 'getHostNameFromAddress()' retrieves the server name by calling 'getnameinfo()', and 'SendConnectToHost()' will construct the CONNECT command string and send it through socket 's'
                            int retBytes = SendConnectlToHost(s, getHostNameFromAddress(name, namelen));
                            return retVal;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Returns the value for Trueconnect()
                return retVal;
            }
        }
    }
    return Trueconnect(s, name, namelen);
}
```

However, this code does not work properly for HTTPS. I don't know what's missing in principal here... Please help. Much appreciated!

**Edit**: Please also note that the client is a Geckofx browser. It is firefox-compliant so I am able to let it trust Fiddler's intercept certificate by overwiting its certificate db files with those copied from my firefox folder. My firefox trusts Fiddler's certificate because I configured it so.

Comment: We could do some hackery to handle the fact that the client is unaware of the proxy and fails to send a `CONNECT`, but the bigger problem is that the client is unlikely to trust Fiddler's interception certificate. What is the client? It's very rare to find an app that uses HTTP/HTTPS but doesn't support a proxy...

Comment: @EricLaw  Hi Eric, the client is a .NET and xulrunner application with Geckofx embedded into it, so I assume it's very similar to firefox internally. It's primarily a chatroom type of program (non-English) with an embedded browser and does not provide a UI component to set proxies. For the hackery approach, is it something that can only be achieved in Fiddler source code as the author? Can the bigger problem be solved if I install fiddler's certificate into Windows trusted root certificates? Do you think it's possible to issue proper CONNECT commands by properly hacking into the socket APIs?

Comment: @EricLaw I've edited the post to add code to detect HTTPS vs HTTP so to insert CONNECT command in case of HTTPS. I've also added explanaion how to let the firefox-complaint client trust Fiddler's certificate. What's still missing? In Fiddler I can see CONNECT was recognized and ssl handshake seems to be initiated but I have no insights where things go wrong afterwards.

Comment: The problem you'll have here is that Fiddler will respond to the `CONNECT` by sending back the `HTTP/200 CONNECTED ...` header block *before* the HTTPS ServerHello. The client will need to eat those bytes for the connection to succeed.

As far as I know, there are flags that can be used to instruct Gecko to use a specific proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503226/how-do-i-change-geckofx-proxy-settings