# C# GeckoFX v45 cannot set GeckoPreferences to set proxy

Tags: c#, casting, properties, geckofx

I am using `GeckoFx v45` and I am trying to set different proxy.
I tried the following which should normally work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox"); //just in case its not already loaded
                GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = UA;
                GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
                //replaced by normal valid proxy and port
                GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http"] = "1.1.1.1";
                GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = "1234";
                GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.ssl"] = "1.1.1.1";
                GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = "1234";

                geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
```

The `GeckoBrowser` will never load and it will remain black.
In the output i see a `'System.InvalidCastException' in Geckofx-Core.dll`.
In the metadata I see this from the `DLL`,

```
public static GeckoPreferences Default { get; }
public static GeckoPreferences User { get; }
```

and I am wondering how can we set that `Property` while it is get-only.
I think this is the issue that is not letting my browser load.
When I remove the `GeckoPreferences` and simply `Navigate` the browser, it works, but without `Proxy` obviously.

If this is the issue then how can I properly set the proxy on a `Gecko Webbrowser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a simple issue. When I added your code to my sample I got a runtime error:

> Additional information: A String value may not be assigned to
>   'network.proxy.http_port' because it is already defined as Int32.

So, 'network.proxy.http_port/ssl_port' needs to be an integer:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = 1234;

GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = 6789;
```

You may also want to look at:

- [Help With Proxy Username & Pass with GeckoFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824858/8291949)
- [How to set different proxies for each GeckoFX instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652385/8291949)